# Re-enable Sudden Motion Sensor

Tags: macos, sensors, dotfiles, motion

I installed Mathias Bynens dotfiles which are very handy but when I check his code it says

```
# Disable the sudden motion sensor as it’s not useful for SSDs
sudo pmset -a sms 0
```

I don't have an SSD and would like to re-enable the Sudden Motion Sensor for my HDD. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pmset),

> sms (supported laptops only) use Sudden Motion Sensor to park disk heads on sudden changes in G force, 1 to enable or 0 to disable

so I guess you'll need to do

```
sudo pmset -a sms 1
```